# How to generate Data Matrix Barcode from Nav 2015?

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, navision, datamatrix, pdf417, microsoft-dynamics-nav

I searched a lot regarding the Data Matrix Code generation from Nav 2015 but could not get any proper solution for that though, i got some code from below link but still, some of the automation variables is not there in Navision, so I need you guys help on this, is there any Code Unit or any object or any other way in Nav..

http://www.barcode-soft.com/dynamics-nav-barcode.aspx

Comment: No standard tool for it in nav

Comment: You can use the "Barcode 128B generation report" by Wolfram Ansin, to generate a barcode. To generate a Matrix Barcode, I think there is no tool avaliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how much time you have to get the barcode.

If it's a back end job, like a report, you can call a command line tool to create the barcode and import the generated image file into a BLOB of a table variable. This table field is then printable within the report.

Another way I use in production is running a web service that creates the barcode and then let Navision create a web page that is opened in a browser window..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a dll (written in C# with ZXING.NET) to generate it and then importing it in NAV.